# How to add a field update to an existing Apex Class

Tags: apex, class, scheduled-apex

I have an existing Apex Class (OpenSource - written by somebody else) that sends an email out on a particular annual date whenever a particular checkbox is ticked, but when the email is sent, I want it to update a datetime field with today's date.

This is the Apex Class:

```
global class AvailUpdateCronJob implements Schedulable{ 

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        sendmail(); 
    }//end execute()

    public List<Id> getAvailUpdateEmailAddresses(Integer Month, Integer Day) 
    { 
        List<Id> mailToIds = new List<Id>();

        Contact[] c = [SELECT Id, email, Availability_Update_Date__c, Send_Availability_Update_A__c, HasOptedOutOfEmail, Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c
                        FROM Contact 
                        WHERE DAY_IN_MONTH(Availability_Update_Date__c) = : Day 
                        AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Availability_Update_Date__c) = : Month   
                        ];

        for(Contact recipient : c) {

                System.Debug('\n*******Found AvailUpdate Recipient');

                if (recipient.Send_Availability_Update_A__c == true && recipient.HasOptedOutOfEmail == false)
                {
                    mailToIds.add(recipient.Id);
                    System.Debug('\n*******Recipient: '+ recipient.email);

                } else {
                    System.Debug('\n*******NO Recipient');
                }

        }

        return mailToIds;
    }//end getAvailUpdateEmailAddresses()

    public void sendMail() 
    {
        String debugAddress = 'eyewell@salesforce.com';
        String AvailUpdateEmailTemplateName = 'CANDIDATE_Availability_Update_A';
        String debugMessage;
        String[] toAddresses;

        Integer DayOfEvent   = date.today().day();
        Integer MonthOfEvent = date.today().month();

        List<Id> AvailUpdateIdsList = getAvailUpdateEmailAddresses(MonthOfEvent,DayOfEvent);

        EmailTemplate availupdateTemplate = [select Id,Name,Subject,body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = :AvailUpdateEmailTemplateName];

        if(availupdateTemplate != null && AvailUpdateIdsList.isEmpty() == false)
        {

            Messaging.MassEmailMessage availupdateMail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();

            availupdateMail.setTargetObjectIds(AvailUpdateIdsList);
            availupdateMail.setTemplateId(availupdateTemplate.Id);
            availupdateMail.setUseSignature(false);
            availupdateMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            // Send the email
            try {
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] { availupdateMail });
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Debug(e);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.Debug('AvailUpdateCronJob:sendMail(): Either an email template could not be found, or no Contact needs an Availability Update');
        }//end if

    }//end sendMail() 

}//end class AvailUpdateCronJob
```

So, right in that // Send the email section (where an email was successfully sent), I'd like to add:

```
Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c = System.now();
```

But I get a **Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c**, which I'm assuming is because I need to call the variable first, and possibily do some other complicated things.

Can anybody help me out with the few lines that I need to get the field update to work?

Comment: I didn't find anywhere in your code you are updating Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c means how you are accessing to update that field directly.

Answer (score 0):

You already have AvailUpdateIdsList for Contacts you mailed. And you can update Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c with something like this:

```
List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c FROM Contact  WHERE Id IN : AvailUpdateIdsList];
for(Contact c : contactsToUpdate)
{
    c.Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c=System.now();
}
update contactsToUpdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Instead of sending the `List<Id>` send the `List<Contact>` directly from `getAvailUpdateEmailAddresses` method so that you don't have to again do the SOQL query and in the send email loop thorugh the `List<Contact>` received from `getAvailUpdateEmailAddresses` and update the `Last_AvailabilityUpdate__c` as well so you have only 1 iteration to do all the stuff.